# HTML Button click, either open form or perform button_click

Tags: html, vb.net

I have vb.net code within form1.

I'm creating in the form1 code behind the following html table.

```
var varHTMLBody as string        
 varHTMLBody = varHTMLBody & "<td><button onclick=""(Button2_Click)""><ID=""myButton""
    <class=""yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-Default yt-uix-button-size-Default""><type=""submit""><role=""button""><span Class=""yt-uix-button-content"">ADD</span></button>" & "</td>" & vbCrLf
```

I'm trying to understand how to solve the following two problems:

1. How to implement a click handler that will just show form2.
2. How to implement a click handler that will perform Button_Click function.

Basically I'd like to know how implement both.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're even trying to do without more context, but what you're doing in that string is *entirely* invalid.  For starters, it's just plain invalid markup.  But even if you correct that, you can't just write `runat="server"` to the client and expect it to actually run on the server.

Comment: I'm sure some things in there don't work.  Its just getting bogged down some trying different thing.  It works however, it adds a button, and I can replace the onclick="" with an alert msg and that works.  However, as I said all I want to do is when you click the button "ADD" that the string adds, I want it either open Form2.vb or invoke Button2_click that is on Form1.vb

Comment: If you're trying to add a server-side control, then you need to create that control server-side.  Currently this is just emitting this string directly to the HTML.  `runat="server"` doesn't mean anything in HTML.

Comment: Ok forget about runat="server", I added that last minute along with 30 other things I was trying.  Even if I take that out the rest of it still functions.  What do I do, if I want the OnClick to either open Form2 or perform Button2_click on Form1??  Everything is local to the app, Nothing is being performed on a server.  Currently it just says "Button2_Click" is undefined when I click the button.

Comment: `"Nothing is being performed on a server"` - Is this even a web application?  The HTML being used implies that it is, but you seem to be saying that it isn't.  This one line of code doesn't really provide any context for what you're trying to do.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Ok.  This is a Desktop APP.  Part of the application pulls some data from a sql server.  That data is displayed in an HTML table.  That's it.  The last column of each row is a button "Add".  That button is generated using the code I posted above.  Once Add is clicked I want it to either open Form2 or perform the Button2_Click that is on Form1 where this code exist.  This is just a VB.NET Windows Form App with 2 Forms.  However I'm using HTML to display data in some tables instead of a VB Control like datagrid or listview.  That's it.

Comment: It seems like the use of HTML here is unnecessarily complicating things.  And I'm really not even how how one would use HTML to perform form-level events.

Comment: It may be entirely impossible and I accept that.  I like the way it looks and the control over it.  If I have to rewrite it to use something else so be it, but I wanted to exhaust all options first.  But thank you.